# Force SSL / https:// using .htaccess for a Content Management System (CMS)

Tags: .htaccess, content-management-system

Content Management Systems often force pages to go though an index.php route.

For example pages on the CMS I use are presented in the URL as follows.

```
http://www.my-domain.co.uk/index.php?page=263
```

The .htaccess code I know only listens to the index.php part of my statement.

My current re-write code stands as follows;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^login/?$ https://www.my-domain.co.uk/login [R=301,L]
```

This works as it is a specific directory, however,

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^index.php?page=263$ https://www.my-domain.co.uk/index.php?page=263 [R=301,L]
```

does not seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are a couple problems with your last rule.  The first parameter to RewriteRule is a regex, so ? has a special meaning.  Also, I'm pretty sure it's looking at the path part of the URL only, not the query string.  Try `^index\.php$`.

Comment: Hi @Sean this idea seems to look in the right direction but again this would re-write all my url requests to HTTPS. as all pages in the cms go through the index.php script.

I assume the \ has the same function as that of vb# script dictating that the following character should be taken as written and should ignore any special meanings?

If this is the case could i write it as index\.php\?page=263$

Answer (score 1):

1. RewriteRule just matches the `path` section of the url, so it needs to be just `^index\.php$`.
2. The query string can be matched using `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`.
3. Like in aesphere's answer, testing for the special `%{HTTPS}` variable is easier than checking the port.
4. Using an absolute target URI implies `[R=301,L]` so you can remove it.
5. [QSA] appends the query string

So, you end up with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\?page=263$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a snippet I copied from a webpage somewhere. Perhaps you could give it a try?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Hi @aesphere would this answer not rewrite all of my URL requests to https?